# send non-flow message from controller to OpenFlow switch

Tags: message, openflow

I'm using a real machine (hp procurve) for my project, I need to send message of other protocol format, OSPF for instance, instead of flows, from controller side to OpenFlow switch through socket(by specifying ip address and port of the OF switch).

But everytime I try to do this, I get "Connection refused" error message, I guess that it might be that the port on OpenFlow switch I'm sending the message to is not listening, so I think I might need to use the same port for the sending which OpenFlow switch uses to talk to the controller, like the port 51067 in the log info :

> - Switch:192.168.1.11:**51067** is connected to the Controller

My question is, how do I retrieve the port information on the controller side, since it is changing every time I restart it? I couldn't find this information.

Or am I going the wrong direction that I need to go another way around instead of sending the message using socket?

Thanks a lot in advance, any suggestions will be appreciated.

jonesir

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? In general you shouldn't try to send non-OpenFlow messages through the OpenFlow control channel (which is what that port on the switch is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the nature of [networking ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29), [protocol numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers), and protocols such as [OSPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First). Let me clear those up:

**Port numbers:** Usually, there is exactly one application listening on a single port: The operating system/networking stack checks each packet of certain types (e.g. TCP or UDP) for the port number and then passes the packet to the application that registered itself for that specific port. If the application cannot handle the received packet then usually it will just ignore it or log an error.

***Aside***: It is possible for two applications to communicate on the same port only if you put some sort of multiplexing application before both (usually a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), possibly a [TCPMUX application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Port_Service_Multiplexer)). This multiplexing application would take incoming packets, determine what type of packet it is and then pass it to the correct application.

**Protocol numbers**: The protocol number is a field inside an IP packet that tells the networking stack what type of data is contained inside. For example, TCP is protocol 6, ICMP is 1, and OSPF is 89.

**OF switches:** Now, logically an OF switch consists of two components: 1) the switching fabric (which includes the physical ports and OF flow tables), and 2) a separate physical port to for out-of-band control, with several applications running behind it. One of these applications is the OpenFlow application, which in your case happens to listen on port 51067. But in real switches, other applications might also be running on different ports, e.g. a web interface running on port 80 for maintenance etc.

**OSPF**: If you now wanted to talk to the application serving the web interface, you'd send a TCP packet with destination port 80 from your controller to the switch. Similarly, if you'd like to install a new flow, you'd send an TCP packet with port 51067 in your case. OSPF is quite different, as it directly uses IP packets and does not use port numbers. To process an OSPF packet, an application needs to use a [raw socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket) to process the incoming IP packets that have protocol number 89, and skip all others. See also the raw manpage [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw). This will already be built into your OF switch.

**Thus, if you want to send an OSPF packet to the OF switch (and your OF switch supports OSPF on the separate physical port!), you'd just send an OSPF IP packet to the switch's IP address (192.168.1.11), no port needed!**

Note that the separate physical port might not support all of the features of the other ports on the OF switch, as they are not intended for the same uses.